# How to dynamically create download links to files saved on server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, model-view-controller

I generate and save .pdf bills on my server.
The files are saved in a "reciept" folder and they look like this:

```
vydej38_1.pdf
vydej38_2.pdf
vydej38_3.pdf
```

I create them dynamically by connecting a contract id (38) to the string and then adding "_1". If I create the file again and it exists, I increment the 1 so I get "_2" etc. I do all of this in controller in PHP.

But now I need to create download links for those files. I can do it for just one file like this

```
<a href="../../receipt/vydej38_1.pdf" download="something.pdf">Download</a>
```

But how can I create the download links dynamically according to the number of files and their names?

Comment: `glob()` `foreach()` profit

Comment: are you wanting to do this is php or javascript?

Comment: it does not really matter, whatever is easier, so I guess it would be php.
Dagon: I see, that looks good. I got to the files with glob("receipt/*.pdf").

Comment: It depends on how you would approach it, either server side, keeping track of files in an SQL table, or you can look at the list of files in a directory dynamically in PHP. I personally like keeping a list of files for organization's sake, though technically the file system itself does that too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dagon for his advice, it was really that simple :)

```
<?php foreach (glob("receipt/*.pdf") as $key => $value): ?>
    <div class="vydejky">
        <a href="../../<?=$value?>" download="vydejka.pdf">Download n. <?=$key?></a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```